# How do we stop Wordpress auto updates

Tags: wordpress

How do we stop Wordpress auto updates with auto updates theme design and functionality for distributed.

Answer (score 1):

you can disable automatic updates in WordPress by adding this line of code in your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

This will disable all automatic WordPress updates.

visit [wpbeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-automatic-updates-in-wordpress/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are after a plugin and not comfortable with editing php files, then I recommend https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-wordpress-updates/ . However I strongly advise that you keep automatic updates turned on, as sometimes they have important security fixes.